# My lists are not displaying side by side or underneath the correct header

Tags: reactjs

I want json data to be parsed into a list and the list to have two headers with the corresponding lists underneath them. I want the lists to be placed side by side but the list is a running list.

I have tried using ng-repeat on my ul classes and centering the text by using align with css but nothing is working.

```
const Header = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1 className="display-3"> lists</h1>
      <br />
      <div className="popularHeader">
        <h1 className="display-4"> Popular List </h1>
      </div>
      <div className="allHeader">
        <h1 className="display-4"> 2nd List </h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

I want two lists displayed side by side.

Comment: I suggest you edit the question and add the piece of code responsible for showing the lists, instead of linking the full codesandbox. Also, how are you using `ng-repeat` in a `react` project?

Comment: In the div id. A user suggested I add a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to show the two lists side by side, with the headers on top.

Check this out:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Reddit lists</h1>
      <div style={{display: "flex"}}>
        <div style={{flex: 1}}>
          <h1>Popular List</h1>
          <PopularList populars={this.state.populars} />
        </div>
        <div style={{flex: 1}}>
          <h1>2nd List</h1>
          <NewList ambers={this.state.ambers} />
        </div>
        <Header />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This works, but it doesn't allow my title to show that I named in the header.js file.

Comment: do you mean the title "Reddit Lists"? I updated the answer to display it

Comment: Mo- how can I add a box around each list item? I tried padding and margin tricks but not working. Is something overriding my css?

Comment: Add a new question for this, showing the relevant piece of code and the output you want to accomplish, and I'm sure people will be happy to help. Tag the question with the `css` tag

Answer (score 1):

You have your headers in separate component and lists in another component. I would suggest that create one component `<PopularList>` with its header inside it followed by the respective list element, another component `<AnotherList>` with its own header inside it, again followed by the respective list.

Then place two components in individual `<div>`, place them side by side using `float` property of CSS. (for proper UI structuring see if you can make use of Bootstrap grid system if it permits)